# Why doesn't my checkbox return a text property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I have this form with this inside it

```
<div class="form-group">
    @*<div class="form-check form-check-box">


    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Features.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-check form-check-box">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Features[i].Selected" value="@Model.Features[i].Text">
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.Features[i].Text">@Model.Features[i].Text</label>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

And when I post the form and inspect the properties of the `SelectedListItem` it looks like this

[image]

Even though the `Selected` should be `True` because I checked it. Everything else that's in the form gets posted fine, like the text input binds just fine to the string Text property inside my ProductModel, I believe the issue is with the way I'm using the checkbox element properties.

So I can see the checkboxes, and I can check them, etc, but when I post the form, nothing related to the checkboxes applies to the ProductModel

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> Features { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I show set the Model for the view

```
public IActionResult PostAd()
{
    var model = new ProductModel
    {
        Features = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Camera", Value = "Camera" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Touch Screen", Value = "Touch Screen" }
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

How do I properly use checkboxes so that when I post the form, the data comes through to the model?
This is the action that gets fired when posting

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateAd(ProductModel Product)
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that when the form is posted, ASP.NET will bind the posted data to your model, but only input *values* within the form are posted. The reason your `SelectListItem` has null `Text` and `Value` properties is because these values are not being posted in the form. The form would need to contain an input (such as a hidden input) for `@Model.Features[i].Text` and another for `@Model.Features[i].Value` for these to be bound back to the `SelectListItem` during model binding because it is the input's `name` that binds it to a model property. But keep in mind, receiving these from even hidden inputs would enable a user to change them to any value they want so you would need to validate on the server side that they are 1) valid values and 2) allowed to be selected.

Given that fact, I find it makes more sense to simply reload the list of available options, in your case `Features`, in your `HttpPost` action, then update that rebuilt list with the user's submitted selections.

Now the only problem left is you're not even getting `Selected` set to true. This is again, because it's based on the input's (the checkbox's) `value`. `asp-for="@Model.Features[i].Selected"` will give the checkbox the `name` it needs to bind back to that property, and will bind its `value` attribute to the value of `Selected`. However, you then also define your own `value` attribute as `value="@Model.Features[i].Text"` which overrides the one that would've been generated by the `asp-for` helper. So when your form is submitted, the model binder tries to bind `"Camera"` to the boolean `Selected` property which can't be done so it just gets it's default `false` value. Generally, a `SelectListItem` is used for a dropdown (`<select>`) input. There's no reason you can't use it for this purpose, but you could also just use your own model type for the checkboxes.